# Incorrect results: mapping c++ array to Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, memory, copy, eigen

I have used the map feature before to map existing memory into Eigen matrices, however when trying to map an fftw c++ array, I am getting wrong results, almost if a portion (a slice?) of the array is being mapped into an Eigen matrix and not the entire memory block. This is the code I am using:

```
static const int nx = 10;
static const int ny = 10; 
static const int nyk = ny/2 + 1;
static const int nxk = nx/2 + 1;
static const int ncomp = 2;

fftw_complex *uhk; // this is pert Te
uhk= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc((((nx)*(ny+1))*nyk)* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
memset(uhk, 42, (((nx))*nyk)* sizeof(fftw_complex));


    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nyk; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < ncomp; k++){
                uhk[i + nyk*j][k] = //taking fft of some expression
        }

    }
    

Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd, Eigen::Unaligned> uhOut(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(uhkOut),nyk,nx);

 std::cout << uhOut<< '\n';
```

The results I am getting are,

```
 (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)
 (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)
 (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)
 (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)
 (0.00,0.00) (0.58,-0.28) (0.95,-0.46) (0.95,-0.46) (0.58,-0.28) (0.00,-0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)
 (0.00,0.00) (0.59,-0.09) (0.95,-0.14) (0.95,-0.14) (0.59,-0.09) (0.00,-0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)  (0.00,0.00)
```

But, the correct result should be:

```
     (0.00,0.00)     (5.14,0.00)     (8.32,0.00)     (8.32,0.00)     (5.14,0.00)     (0.00,0.00)    (-5.14,0.00)    (-8.32,0.00)    (-8.32,0.00)    (-5.14,0.00)
     (0.00,0.00)    (2.43,-2.35)    (3.93,-3.81)    (3.93,-3.81)    (2.43,-2.35)    (0.00,-0.00)    (-2.43,2.35)    (-3.93,3.81)    (-3.93,3.81)    (-2.43,2.35)
     (0.00,0.00)    (0.52,-1.04)    (0.85,-1.68)    (0.85,-1.68)    (0.52,-1.04)    (0.00,-0.00)    (-0.52,1.04)    (-0.85,1.68)    (-0.85,1.68)    (-0.52,1.04)
     (0.00,0.00)    (0.57,-0.55)    (0.93,-0.89)    (0.93,-0.89)    (0.57,-0.55)    (0.00,-0.00)    (-0.57,0.55)    (-0.93,0.89)    (-0.93,0.89)    (-0.57,0.55)
     (0.00,0.00)    (0.58,-0.28)    (0.95,-0.46)    (0.95,-0.46)    (0.58,-0.28)    (0.00,-0.00)    (-0.58,0.28)    (-0.95,0.46)    (-0.95,0.46)    (-0.58,0.28)
     (0.00,0.00)    (0.59,-0.09)    (0.95,-0.14)    (0.95,-0.14)    (0.59,-0.09)    (0.00,-0.00)    (-0.59,0.09)    (-0.95,0.14)    (-0.95,0.14)    (-0.59,0.09)
```

Am I misunderstanding the point of `map` here? Why are my results sliced like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're computing your offsets wrong.  `[i+nyk*j]` is not correct.  The largest value of j is (nyk-1).  I think you meant for it to be `[i*njk+j]`.

To diagnose this sort of problem, I suggest doing

`uhk[j + nyk*i][k] = (k==0)?i:j; // Note I swapped i/j in the offsets`

This will create a matrix where the real portions match the column number, and the imaginary portions are the row number.  A simple pattern like this makes it obvious the values aren't being correctly written the expected memory locations.

Comment: you're right this actually fixed the problem significantly by changing to ``[i*njk+j]`` but it flips my rows and columns I think since c++ arrays are row-major vs Eigen is column-major I believe so.